# Loading ListView Elements only when visible

Tags: java, android, listview, bitmap

I currently encountered a Problem working with the ListView in Android. The Problem is that I want to load HD-Images from the SD-Card and display them in a ListView, but now the pictures take up so much memory that the Application crashes.
Here you can see my PictureListAdapter:

```
private Activity activity;
private File[] objects;

public PictureListAdapter(Activity activity, File[] objects) {
    super(activity, R.layout.list_element, objects);
    this.activity = activity;
    this.objects = objects;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.activity.getLayoutInflater();
    View zeile = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_element, null, true);

    ImageView pictureView = (ImageView) zeile.findViewById(R.id.image_item);
    Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(position);
    if (bmp != null) {
        pictureView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }

    return zeile;
}
private Bitmap getBitmap(int position) {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(objects[position].getAbsolutePath());
}
```

As you can see the Pictures are given in a File[] and I would like to keep it that way.

Hope you can help me

Comment: Why you don't use `convertView` in the adapter? You need to pass `false` as last parameter of your `inflate()`. Show stack trace.

Comment: I didn't know about the convertView. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can scale down your bitmaps before rendering them to the list view like so:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 4;
return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(objects[position].getAbsolutePath(), options);
```

This will scale the image down to 1/4 is dimensions and 1/16 the pixels. Look it up in the API guide